# Change svg group element center

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to translate the center of a svg group to its left top corner:

Instead of:

```
+-----------------+       x-----------------+
|                 |       |                 |
|                 |       |                 |
|                 |       |                 |
|        x        | ----> |                 |
|                 |       |                 |
|                 |       |                 |
|                 |       |                 |
+-----------------+       +-----------------+
```

So, for following svg:

```
<svg width="900" height="900">
    <g transform="translate(200,300)">
        <rect width="400" height="500"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The `rect` element should be on absolute position: `0, 50` (`200 - 400 / 2`, `300 - 500 / 2`).

I know I can set `x` and `y` attributes to `rect` element (`<rect width="400" height="500" x="-200" y="-250"></rect>`), but this is more or less a hack since the real center of `g` is not changed.

What's the proper way to change the center of a `<g>` SVG element?

```css
rect {
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="900" height="900">
    <g transform="translate(200,300)">
        <rect width="400" height="500" x="-200" y="-250"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this works for you as a `translate`?

```css
rect {
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="900" height="900">
  <g transform="translate(200,300)">
    <g transform="translate(-200, -250)">
      <rect width="400" height="500"></rect>    
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'd like a *more native* way that doesn't count on group width/height.

Comment: I think you can use percentages as well there.